# C# Protobuf: 'Protocol message contained a tag with an invalid wire type.'

Tags: c#, binary, protocol-buffers

I am trying to read some protobuf data from a collegue - he created it in C++ and set the encoding to unicode, and transfer mode for protobuf is binary.

In python, this works perfectly:

```
with open('test.out', 'rb') as f:
    dfile = protoclass_pb2.DataFile()
    dfile.ParseFromString(f.read())
    print(dfile.MetaData.author)
```

just like a charm.

In C# howevern, I try:

```
string filepath = "test.out"
FileStream fst = new FileStream(filepath, 
DataFile data = DataFile.Parser.ParseDelimitedFrom(fst);
fst.Close();
```

and get the Exception:

```
Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 'Protocol message contained a tag with an invalid wire type.'
```

I tired somehow setting an encoding to the stream, but as far I can tell, I can only set encoding to `StreamReader` but not `Stream` itself.

Just reading the file content to an array produces the same in both languages.

How can I read the data in to C#?

Comment: protobuf data is binary (unless you're talking about the json variant), so there shouldn't *be* an encoding - if you're specifying an encoding, it suggests you're going via a text layer, which would be incorrect; if you want, you can use either `protoc` or [this site](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode) to validate whether the payload is valid (i.e. hasn't been corrupted in write/transfer)

Comment: it looks like your C# code closes the file *before* you read from it, and the `new FileStream` line seems to be truncated?

Comment: Try adding a flush before the close : fst.Flush(); fst.Close();

Comment: @MarcGravell My bad when copying to stack overflow. File is of course still open. If the file is closed, the exception also says so.

Comment: Also, since reading in python works and the correct values are in the fields, I do not think anything has been corrupted.

Comment: @user3696412 best to actually validate that assumption, though... it takes literally seconds, so./..

Comment: The decoder page does parse it and does not display any errors. However, it also does not display any error when I just go in with Notepad++ and delete half of the file... so I don't really know what to make from it. When uploading a different file (`packages.config` was lying around in the same folder handily) I get an error...

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: the collegue serialized the message with `SerializeToOstream` and I tried reading with `ParseDelimitedFrom`.

Easlily fixed by either using `SerializeDelimitedToOstream` to serialize or `ParseFrom` to read.